# Close app during HTTP Call

Tags: ios

I just want to ask if the HTTP call in IOS will be cancel when I close the app so that I can handle it properly. I've already search in the internet but I do not found any related answer for my question.

Comment: What do you mean by closed?

Comment: If your app going to background (press 'Home' button), HTTP request will NOT be cancel and continue waiting for response when your app become active.

Comment: Add one, HTTP request does have a timeout.